# What does Go Version means?

Tags: docker

```
docker version
```

outputs

```
docker emulating version 0.1.3
client version: 0.5
server version: 0.5
go version: go 1.1
```

What does go version means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Go](http://golang.org/) is a programming language with an inconvenient name, made by Google.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Docker engine has two parts one is daemon and other is client. So client server version means daemon and clent part versions. Am i clear? What is the use of Go in docker?

Comment: @user3801433: docker is written in go. :) And uses go runtime, obviously (that's why knowing its version is important)